# FCM upstream messages to device group not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send messages between user's own device. It is like a broadcast to user's own devices. So, I created a device group with user's devices' instance ids. And when I am sending message from the Postman, both of the user's devices receives the messages. But, when I try to send the message from the device, found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group#sending_upstream_messages_to_device_groups) in the documentation:

```
                FirebaseMessaging fm = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
                String to = "1234"; // the notification key
                AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
                fm.send(new RemoteMessage.Builder(to)
                      .setMessageId(Integer.toString(msgId.incrementAndGet()))
                      .addData("hello", "world")
                      .build());
```

I tried, `notification group key`, `notification group name`, `random number`, but nothing worked. No error messages.

Also, I tried to check the response by overriding `onMessageSent` method. But it always returns `1`. Don't know what does that mean.

The reason I am trying to do with FCM is battery efficient and no persistence connection to firebase database needed. But It seems like sending upstream messages requires a middleware to handle all messages. But, it gets tricky if I need a server to handle all the messages and not possible for me to host a server.

Am I missing any basics? I am new to gcm/fcm. Why my simple code is not working and always returns 1?